# Android Application blocks adding SDK Facebook GoogleService AndroidBootstrap

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an Android application which needs the 4 following Project Libraries: SDK Facebook, Google Play Services (for showing a map) AndroidBootstrap and android-support-v7-appcompat.

I added them importing as an Existing Android Project, copying them in my workspace and adding in my project:(in Eclipse, right button on the project -> properties -> Android -> Add.. .Like this:

[image]

I added in the Java Build Path others libraries I need like ormlite.

All the project was working correctly including the Activity which shows the map, but suddenly, this activity stops working giving the following error and it never worked again:

**ERROR**

```
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): Process: com.bora, PID: 3089
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bora/com.bora.MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class fragment
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class fragment
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at com.bora.MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity.onCreate(MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity.java:31)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     ... 10 more
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:618)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     ... 21 more
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.bora-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:604)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     ... 25 more
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):         ... 27 more
03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
03-16 13:57:18.336: W/ActivityManager(498):   Force finishing activity com.bora/.MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity
```

Here are all the files which refers to the map:

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bora"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


   <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.bora.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>




    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.bora.SplashFragment" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"
        >

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name="com.bora.MenuPrincipalListViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <activity android:name="com.bora.MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <activity android:name="com.bora.SplashRapidoActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <activity android:name="com.bora.DialogBusqueda" android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/dialog_light"/>
    <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"/>
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

**R.layout.menuprincipal_map_view**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:context=".MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="3" >
                <LinearLayout 
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:layout_weight="1"  
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                >
                         <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_event_list"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:background="@color/Aqua"
                            android:text="Eventos"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            android:textColor="@color/gris_letra"
                             android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            />
            </LinearLayout>  
            <LinearLayout 
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                >         
                       <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_map"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="Mapa!"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/Aqua"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                             />
            </LinearLayout>            
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1" >

                            <fragment
                                android:id="@+id/map" 
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

 </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="3" >
                <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_search"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="@string/simbolo_buscar"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/gris_letra"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"

                             />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_search_dialog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

        </LinearLayout> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

An here the **MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity**:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.bora.database.DatabaseManager;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

public class MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

```
   Button Eventos,  Buscar;
   //  SupportMapFragment Mapa;
   DatabaseManager mDatabaseManager;
   MapFragment mapFragment;
   private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.menuprincipal_map_view);
        mDatabaseManager = new DatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
        Eventos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_event_list);
        Buscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_search);


    //   Mapa = (SupportMapFragment) ((FragmentActivity) getApplicationContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById( R.id.map);
        Buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });

        if(!mDatabaseManager.Busqueda_actualExists() || !mDatabaseManager.BusquedaisUpdated())
        {
            showDialog();
        }

        Eventos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuPrincipalListViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }
     private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
            // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    //        if (mMap == null) {
                // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
    //          mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    //                  mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        //        if (mMap != null) {
        //            setUpMap(); 
        //        }
      //      }
         mapFragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
         mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                     @Override
                     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                         googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                            .title("Marker"));
                         setUpMap();
                     }
                 });
        } 

        /**
         * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
         * just add a marker near Africa.
         * <p>
         * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
         */
        private void setUpMap() {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        }
        /*@Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Marker"));
        }*/
    public void showDialog()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, DialogBusqueda.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
}       

        /**
         * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
         * just add a marker near Africa.
         * <p>
         * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
         */
        private void setUpMap() {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        }
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Marker"));
        }
    public void showDialog()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, DialogBusqueda.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
}
```

So, this is the issue, if I CHECK in Build Java Path any of these libraries (red circle in the following photo) Eclipse blocks showing the Internal Problem: "Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded GC overhead limit exceeded". Note that I have already changed my `eclipse.ini` using the info [here](https://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) for solve the potencial error ( I read that maybe this error is caused beacause a loop is created diferent versions of the same libraries).

[image]

If I don't check these libraries the First **ERROR** is shown.

So, I thought that, maybe could be a problem with the `android-support-v4.jar` library because, AndroidBootstrap, SDK Facebook, android-support-v7-appcompat and my project has different version of `android-support-v4.jar`.

What I did:
0 - I copied the `google-play-services.jar` in myproject/lib and referenced that in Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs (without results, so I deleted it from my project).

1 - I copied the last version (which is in `android-support-v7-appcompat/lib`) and pasted in the `/lib` folder of AndroidBootstrap, SDK Facebook  and my own project.

2 - I Read in some post that maybe a problem is the AndroidTarget from these Libraries and project, so, I changed all the targets (from libraries and project) to the same one `Google APIs 22`.

3 - I clean and rebuild all of them.

The problem persists.

So, I tried to uninstall google-play-services and reinstall again from the AndroidSDK without results.

I tried to create a new Workspace an do all the steps again but nothing works.

The funny thing is that at the beginning all was working correctly, including the map.

Any idea?

Comment: make your question more compact as nobody will dig thru such bunch of content

Comment: 1. getMap() is deprecated 2. post R.layout.menuprincipal_map_view 3. which line of which xml this refers to 03-16 13:57:18.311: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bora/com.bora.MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: com.bora/com.bora.MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity is the Activity I posted.  R.layout.menuprincipal_map_view is the xml layout I posted. I have updated the name files. What I have to type instead of getMap()?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMap%28%29

Comment: I modified the MenuPrincipalMapViewActivity an the same error persists (updated above). Do you know why is not finding the  `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Comment: mapFragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)); what is R.id.map?

Comment: The Fragment in the layout. You can find that in the R.layout.menuprincipal_map_view

Comment: I dont see anything with id set to R.id.map in that xml, so check again

Comment: My apologies! check it now!